# REST URI with same attribute in both Path Params and Request Body

Tags: rest, restful-url, http-put

I'm writing an API to update a `UserDetail` POJO which looks like

```
UserDetail {
    private String userId;
    private String userName;
    private String address;
}
```

For writing REST URI to update, I'm using following URI

```
@Path("/user/{userId}")
@PUT
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
void updateUser(@PathParam("userId") String userId,
                @NonNull UserDetail userDetail);
```

Is there some convention around using same attributes in both Path Parameters and Request Body? I'm facing the issue that since `userId` is present in both URI and Body, I'll have to validate if both of them are same, otherwise throw Exception/Override one with other/..!

Comment: IMO, (if possible) just remove `private String userId;` from `UserDetail`. Otherwise, you will have to document that those two must have same value.

Comment: @BheshGurung So in my application, I've modeled my resources along with the unique identifiers which I think makes more sense since they are coupled together. For example, I have my database entity as {userId, userName, address, ... , }, and it made more sense to me by modeling the REST Entity in the same way as DB Entity. Your thoughts?

Comment: Modeling your REST entities based on your DB entities is ok.  in some cases they are same and you can even use same java POJO fod both. But in a lot of other cases, like this, they are quiet different from each other. Where if you want to make your API endpoint meaningful, its implementation part should be different and decoupled from how you implement the  other parts of your application. In other words, DB entities cannot always represent REST entities also.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why that is a problem. What you would like to to do is:

`if(!stringId.equals(useDetail.getUserId()))
    throw new Exception()`

You will need to generate getters for the UserDeatail class or make the variables public.

In case of POST you probably shouldn't put the id in the path. With GET, DELETE and PUT you are expected to use the path for the ID.

> GET   /device-management/devices : Get all devices
>
> POST  /device-management/devices : Create a new device
>
> GET   /device-management/devices/{id} : Get the device information identified by "id"
>
> PUT   /device-management/devices/{id} : Update the device information identified by "id"
>
> DELETE    /device-management/devices/{id} : Delete device by "id"

Comment: Yes! I know this is what I need to do in this case. But I was looking for what conventions people follow while modeling their Resources. Does it makes sense to put identifiers along with entity, or keep them separate?

Comment: So with GET, should the result entity also contain "id" or not?

Comment: In my opinion it shouldn't if the client doesn't have any business logic with the id.